# Python Docxtpl вставить данные в таблицу в файл .docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jinja2, python-docx

Есть файл формата docx. В нем есть шапка таблицы: Фамилия, Имя, Отчество.

Имеется ли возможность вставки данных посредством библиотеки python docxtpl в этот файл?
Конечное количество данных не известно и всегда формируется динамически. 1 человека получается вставить данные {{ sname }} {{ fname }} {{ tname }}. Как быть, если данных будет больше?

Как можно это организовать?

Comment: А не легче всё вставить в excel библиотекой CSV?

Comment: Задача вставить именно в .docx. Так я бы давно вставил иной библиотекой: CSV или openpyxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После прочтения мануалов пришел к выводу, что для данной операции лучше всего использовать python библиотеку **docx**:

```
...
from docx import Document
...
```

Затем, создаем экземпляр:

```
doc = Document('test.docx')
```

Теперь можно обратиться к таблицам, которые уже есть в данном документе:

```
doc.tables[0]
```

и добавлять нужные сроки, вставлять в них данные. Например:

```
...
doc.tables[0].add_row()
doc.tables[0].cell(0,0).text = 'exmpl'
...
```

Возможно данная информация будет полезна. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.